# Select Layer By Location gives ERROR 000840 ({select_features} as arcpy.Polygon)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-2.7, select-by-location, error-000840

I tried to select **SC27060054** point object using polygon.
**r"Project\project.DBO.Qo"** is a point layer.

```
import arcpy

p1 = arcpy.Point(254426.380,  4664270.258)
p2 = arcpy.Point(254432.730,  4664270.258)
p3 = arcpy.Point(254432.730,  4664264.967)
p4 = arcpy.Point(254426.380,  4664264.967)

poly = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([p1, p2, p3, p4]))

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(r"Project\project.DBO.Qo", "CONTAINS", poly)
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7279, in SelectLayerByLocation
raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. 
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Boolean. Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).

desc = arcpy.Describe(r"Project\project.DBO.Qo")
print desc.shapeType
Point
```

[image]

Comment: `"WITHIN"` or `"INTERSECT"` must be in place `"CONTAIN"` in line : `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(r"Project\project.DBO.Qo", "CONTAINS", poly)`, but this rises the same error. In ArcGIS Documentation we read : _The features in the input feature layer will be selected based on their relationship to the features from this layer or feature class_. So `arcpy.Polygon` is feature class, right ?

Answer (score 3):

For Select Layer by Location `in_layer` and `select_features` needs to be feature layers, for example created with [MakeFeatureLayer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) (or by adding a feature class to ArcMap and execute code in the Python window using the name of the feature layer from table of contents).
So both `"Project\project.DBO.Qo"` and `poly` need to be layers.

Try:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Project\project.DBO.Qo" , "Qolyr")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(poly, r"in_memory\poly") #You need a feature class to create a feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"in_memory\poly", "polylyr")
```

And then use `"Qolyr"` and `"polylyr"` in Select Layer by Location.

Also, if Qolyr is a Point layer it can never contain polygons:

> CONTAINS —The features in the input layer will be selected if they
>   contain a selecting feature.

You probably want intersect:

> INTERSECT —The features in the input layer will be selected if they
>   intersect a selecting feature. This is the default.

Comment: I've tried what you wrote, but same error ... arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Qolyr", "CONTAINS", "polylyr")

Comment: @dimmed, if Qolyr are Points, they can never contain polygons. Try Another overlap type, for example INTERSECT, to see if this is what is causing the error

Comment: When I am trying to do arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Qolyr", "INTERSECT", "polylyr") equivalent "Select By Location ..." from graphical interface of ArcGIS  works fine but not from Python console. Why ?

Comment: @dimmed do you get an error or what do you mean by not working

Comment: I got same error

Comment: I experimented with different layers and overlap_types. It comes out that from Python console Select By Location doesn't work.